# Detecting current color in window

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am doing a beginner project and I have had a little issue with a radio button. This button's job is to change the theme of the window from light to dark and vice versa.

I'm not too sure on how to ask for Java to detect the value for the `Color.decode()` method. I want it to check if the current color is either "#21252B" or "#FFFFFF"

I expect it to look kind of like:

```java
if(*however you are supposed to do it*.equals("#21252B")) {
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.decode("#FFFFFF"));
    darkMode.setBackground(Color.decode("#FFFFFF"));
} else {
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.decode("#21252B"));
    darkMode.setBackground(Color.decode("#21252B"));
}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what I had to do. Thanks to @AndrewThompson for the suggestion. If anyone needs an answer to a similar problem, here it is. Make

```java
private boolean isDark = true //or false if you want from the get go.
```

Then, whenever you do your button do the following code

```java
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    if(isDark == true) {
        lightTheme();
        isDark = false;
    } else {
        darkTheme();
        isDark = true;
    }
```

after this you should be good to go.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! Again, I'd recommend looking into the Pluggable Look and Feel. There are no inbuilt ones that do a dark / bright variant, but among the 3rd party PLAFs there are a few (AFAIR). Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) for code (mostly about layouts) which shows how to change the PLAF with various screen shots of how the standard PLAFs appear. In this case however, presumably the only difference would be in the colors used to paint containers and components.

Comment: `if(isDark == true) {` can be shortened to `if(isDark) {`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll look into PLAF

Comment: Oh .. and, don't forget to 'accept' this answer to let others know there is a solution to be had here.